# How to hide common assembly classes?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, encapsulation

I'm developing a piece of software that is split up into multiple projects, which you can think of as:

- Client
- Server
- Common

Client and Server both reference Common, and use classes from it. For this reason, the classes in Common are public. However, although I want them to be used by Client and Server, I don't want them to be used by outside code that is using the Client and Server libraries.

Marking the classes as internal is clearly not an option. Is there a way I could make them available to Client and Server, but hide them from the outside world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You disqualify `internal` since you assume your other `Assemblies` won't be able to use the `internal` `Types`, which is not necessarily true.

[`InternalsVisibleToAttibute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) is an `Assembly Attribute` which allows you to make the `internal` `Types` of one projects visible to other selected projects.

This way you can make the common types `internal` but use this `Attribute` to make them visible to *Server* and *Client*.

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Client", "PublicKey=2345456456...")]
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Server", "PublicKey=5345347366...")]
```

In my opinion, `internal` is a generally a little bit of a code smell... It doesn't really protect your code as much as making it harder to be extended later... I would just keep the `Types` `public` and use the XML documents to assure that the one who uses my `Types` will use them as I meant them to be used, but that's just my point of view...

Comment: I don't agree with `internal` being a code smell; there are times when you want that level of encapsulation, as some classes are intended only as helper classes within the same assembly and would only confuse outside users. (I agree with the rest of your solution though.)

Comment: It's a matter of balance, I just think the extensibility of my code is more important than making someone read my documentation (which can also state that this class is for internal usages), but again it's just my own opinion :)

Comment: I know what you mean. What bothers me (in my opinion) is seeing many classes coming up in intellisense that I wouldn't normally use. A well-designed library shouldn't provide multiple ways to do the same thing (because that's a common cause of confusion).

Comment: @Gigi If intellisense is a problem, you can put these classes in a separate namespace.

Comment: They are in a separate namespace. That doesn't keep people from accessing them.

Comment: Why do you care people accessing them? If it's security reasons `internal` doesn't help you anyway, if it's that you don't want people to make mistakes well... you can't prevent it 100% all the time, and with `internal` you pay a big price preventing it...

Answer (score 3):

Another option, beside attribute `InternalsVisibleTo`, is to create `Common` project as Shared Project (available in VS 2015) in this way `Client` and `Server` will have access to internal classes because shared project will be included in assembly of each of them and not moved to separate assembly as in case with Class Library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `internal` classes and [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `Common` assembly. Add the attribute to the `AssemblyInfo` of the `Common` project and specify the assemblies that will have access to its `internal`s.

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Client")]
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Server")]
```

Although I would just make the types `public`.